# Is there a function in python or R that estimates the limit of a sequence based on a group of points?

Tags: python, r

Say I have 5 points that follow the path of a converging function, but I don't know the function. Is there a function that uses the points to estimate the limit?

Comment: @MattDMo what is being described is extrapolation rather than interpolation, and I'm not sure that interpolation techniques would work if one doesn't know the form of the underlying function. I'm happy to be proved wrong though.

Comment: Only five points is very little for extrapolation to a limit

Comment: I'd suggest this is off-topic for Stack Overflow and a better fit for Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com). It's not really a programming question, more of a methods question.

Comment: @GregorThomas Ok. I didn't really know the difference between them.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, I think this is also a programming question. But it need to be specific. @Johnny, as Allan Cameron suggested, it's technically impossible to estimate a limit without a model. Choose a suitable model and use ```scipy.optimize.curve_fit()```. Of course, you will get the parameters and need to get the limit analytically(Or numerically by using a library such as Sympy).